# Gatekeeper fatal problems when building on macOS Big sur

Tags: codesign, osx-gatekeeper

I have serious problems with the "security" stuff. First, there is an installer package (PKG).
Works without problems on all (most?) macOS with catalina and newer (probably). But trying it on 10.11 and older results in macOS saying that it is corrupted or signature is invalid, and console contains this:

03.12.20 17:32:42,194 CoreServicesUIAgent[331]: Error -60005 creating authorization

It has been signed and notarized, so this looks like a bug in macOS.

And then there's another software we make, this time it is installed using an APP. Again, codesigned and notarized and works on most macOS systems, including the older ones, but this time there are rare machines, which end up with the exact same message and the console contains:

com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.oneshot.0x10000006.setup.bin[2242]): removing service since it exited with consistent failurae - OSREASONEXEC | Gatekeeper policy blocked execution

Any ideas what is wrong exactly?

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that Apple f*** up again - when you create installers on the new revolutionary awesome macOS Big sur, on some computers your installers won't pass Gatekeeper. Doing the same thing on Catalina -> everything fine. Damn you Apple...